Figma plugin API delay in loading all children form a node
I am working on developing a Figma plugin using their API.
As per the below code, I'm trying to access a specific node in the mainLayer.children, but when mainLayer is logged to the console it shows children with length 2 which has a a readout-layer name node,  but when readoutLayer is logged it is empty.
const mainLayer = figma.currentPage.children.find((layer) => layer.name === 'main-layer') as GroupNode;
let readoutLayer = mainLayer.children.filter((layer) => layer.name === 'readout-layer') as GroupNode[];

console.log("==mainLayer==>", mainLayer) // GroupNode {id: '318:1123'} is consoled
console.log("==mainLayer==>", mainLayer.children) // [GroupNode] is consoled
console.log("==readoutLayer==>", readoutLayer )  // [] is consoled

Is there any reason why the readout-layer named node is not available, while mainLayer has it when logged individually. Also I don't want to use setTimeout since I don't want delays and control moving to the next code line
